# If post exists and post_meta exists

Tags: wordpress, function, if-statement

In my plugin I have a form with a couple of input fields (**customer_name** and **customer_email**) which creates a post when submitted.

When submitted, I'm also checking to see if a post with the same **post_title** already exists in the database:

```
// posts
$customer_name = sanitize_text_field($_POST['customer_name']);
// post_meta
$customer_email = sanitize_text_field($_POST['customer_email']);

if( post_exists($customer_name) ) {
    // the post exists, update the post
} else {
    // the post does not exist, add new post
}
```

..which works fine.

But what I need to do is not only check if the **customer_name** already exists, but also check if that **customer_name** already has a **customer_email** (in post_meta) the same as the one that was submitted.

By doing this I will know if I need to update an existing post or create a new post.

Comment: did you try with `metadata_exists('post', $post_id, 'customer_email ');`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $post_id = post_exists($customer_name)  

if($post_id){

 if ( metadata_exists( 'post', $post_id, 'customer_email' ) ) {
        // Customer email exist

            $post_customer_email = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'customer_email', true );
            if($post_customer_email == $customer_email){
                echo "already exist"; // do your stuff here
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: How will I know the $post_id? I mean, at this stage, is there a $post_id?

Comment: @user3256143 post_exists() function return post_id if exist